# Make changes to child with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent

I have a file directory with little thumbnails for each file that indicates its filetype. However, I want the thumbnails to be more specific for certain files.

For example, I have a Sketch-File, a Photoshop-File, a JPG and a PNG. The mime-type-algorithm detects all of those four files as an image. However, I want to replace that image-thumbnail of the sketch- and psd-file.

Now, I want to change the 'style' attribute of the child div related to the file-extension. If the extension of the data-file-attribute is .psd > then change div#thumbnail's style-attribute to .../filetypes/psd.svg. If data-file-attribute is .sketch > div#thumbnails's stle-attribute should be .../filetypes/sketch.svg.

However, the thumbnail for PNGs and JPGs should remain the same.

How can this be done? Any ideas? I am new to jQuery.

My HTML looks like this:

```html
<tr data-file="filename.png" data-mime="application/octet-stream">
  <td class="td_01">
    <a class="name">
      <div class="thumbnail" style="background-image:url(/img/filetypes/image.svg)"></div>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr data-file="filename.jpg" data-mime="application/octet-stream">
  <td class="td_01">
    <a class="name">
      <div class="thumbnail" style="background-image:url(/img/filetypes/image.svg)"></div>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr data-file="filename.psd" data-mime="application/octet-stream">
  <td class="td_01">
    <a class="name">
      <div class="thumbnail" style="background-image:url(/img/filetypes/image.svg)"></div>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr data-file="filename.sketch" data-mime="application/octet-stream">
  <td class="td_01">
    <a class="name">
      <div class="thumbnail" style="background-image:url(/img/filetypes/image.svg)"></div>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you :

It looks for all the tr in the document.

For each tr, it tries to find .psd or .sketch. If one of the two is found, then the bakcground image is modified. If not, it doesn't do anything.

Edit : it's written in plain  js, it doesn't use JQuery.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <table>
  <tr data-file="filename.png" data-mime="application/octet-stream">
    <td class="td_01">
      <a class="name">
        <div class="thumbnail" style="background-image:url(/img/filetypes/image.svg)"></div>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr data-file="filename.jpg" data-mime="application/octet-stream">
    <td class="td_01">
      <a class="name">
        <div class="thumbnail" style="background-image:url(/img/filetypes/image.svg)"></div>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr data-file="filename.psd" data-mime="application/octet-stream">
    <td class="td_01">
      <a class="name">
        <div class="thumbnail" style="background-image:url(/img/filetypes/image.svg)"></div>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr data-file="filename.sketch" data-mime="application/octet-stream">
    <td class="td_01">
      <a class="name">
        <div class="thumbnail" style="background-image:url(/img/filetypes/image.svg)"></div>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  let tr = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
  for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
   let t = tr[i];
   if(t.dataset.file.indexOf('.psd') >= 0){
    t.querySelector('div').style.backgroundImage = "url(img/filetypes/psd.svg)";
   }else if(t.dataset.file.indexOf('.sketch') >= 0){
    t.querySelector('div').style.backgroundImage = "url(img/filetypes/sketch.svg)";
   } 
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```